# Ruby handle error in child class first

Tags: ruby, inheritance, error-handling

Is it possible in ruby to have a parent class method that handles an exception, and a child that will handle the error first if the child class is used.

In other words:

```
class Parent
  def eat_apples(param)
    puts "eat apples #{param}"
    raise "pooey"

  rescue => e
    puts "parent error handler"
  end
end


class Child < Parent
  def eat_apples(param)
    super(param)

  rescue => e
    puts "child error handler"
  end
end
```

is it possible to call `Child.new.eat_apples('something')` and have the child handle the error before the parent?

I pretty much want to do the same thing in the parent/child class, but the functionality differs at the error handling step

Comment: Nope, not without a change--the entire `eat_apples` will run, including its error handling.

Comment: Not true @DaveNewton, You can do the extended class error handling prior to calling the super method.

Comment: @BillyFerguson Which... would be a change.

Comment: Apologies sir. I misunderstood your comment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why not just redefine the method without calling super?

```
class Child < Parent
  def eat_apples(param)
    puts "eat apples #{param}"
    raise "pooey"

  rescue => e
    puts "child error handler"
  end
end
```

Comment: You know how Peter is.

Answer (score 1):

This isn't the best example as I cannot see the kind of use case you are looking to handle. However, with that said you should be able to handle the child error first by doing the child error handling prior to calling the parent method with `super`.

```
class Parent
  def eat_apples(param)
    puts "eat apples #{param}"
    raise "pooey"

  rescue => e
    puts "parent error handler"
  end
end


class Child < Parent
  def eat_apples(param)
    if param != "apple"
      raise
    end
    super(param)
  rescue => e
    puts "child error handler"
  end


end
```

Answer (score 1):

Add a default parameter to the method and super call? This gives you the freedom to customize the parent and child exceptions as you like without having to give up the parent exception, as suggested by @Mark.

```
class Parent
  def eat_apples(param,throwitdown=false)
    puts "eat apples #{param}"
    raise "pooey"

  rescue => e
    raise e if throwitdown
    puts "parent error handler"
  end
end


class Child < Parent
  def eat_apples(param)
    super(param,true)

  rescue => e
    puts "child error handler"
  end
end

puts Parent.new.eat_apples('from parent')
puts Child.new.eat_apples('from child')
```

Answer (score 0):

Create a method that raises an exception in parent class, and create an another method that handles exception for the error raised. Now in child class eat_apples method, call the parent method that raises exception and let child handle the exception. Like below

```
class Parent
  def eat_apples!(param)
    puts "eat apples #{param}"
    raise "pooey"
  end

  def eat_apples(param)
    eat_apples!(param)
  rescue => e
    puts "parent error handler"
  end
end


class Child < Parent
  def eat_apples(param)
   eat_apples!(param)
  rescue => e
    puts "child error handler"
  end
end
```